# Changing the sitemap after SSL installation

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, ssl, sitemaps

I recently installed SSL and edited .htaacess file.( for proper redirection). Recently, I found that the XML sitemap is referring to the non-SSL version as in the picture.
[image]

Magento ver. 1.9.3.4

Is there any way to change these URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Recreate the sitemap and resubmit it. There is another way to redirect all non ssl url to ssl via htaccess but that is not recommended as it added unwanted logic. Best resubmit sitemap again.

Comment: The sitemap is already created and lists the required URLs. Is there any solution to add the HTTPS instead of HTTP to that listed URLs in the sitemap?

Comment: Do Find and replace if you don't want to regenerate

Comment: Is there any other solution?